# How can I cut a (reverse) waterdrop shape out of a cardstock perfectly?

Tags: paper, cardboard, papercutting

I have printed the waterdrop shape on the cardstock. I want it to have sharp and smooth edges. I'm not an artisan at crafts, however, scissors and utility knife leave a lot of roughness.

[image: Preview]

Comment: Are you cutting corrugated cardboard, or "cardstock"?

Comment: I didn't know its name was cardstock, will fix it right now.

Comment: When you say "reverse" do you mean you want a water drop shaped hole in an otherwise intact piece of card and not a tear drop shaped piece of card?

Comment: @smithkm I mean a cardstock punched in the form of a reverse water drop.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a makerspace in your area or a similar craft related activity/club, you may be able to gain use of a craft cutter such as the Silhouette Cameo or a Cricut product. Still associated with the makerspace, you may find members with a laser cutter. Stretching the application a bit means you could also use a flatbed CNC machine to make the straight and large curves, although the small point at the bottom would have to be done by hand with a sharp craft knife.

I've recently become aware of a product that can be best described as a high-frequency vibrating craft knife. At a cost of US$399, it's steep for hobby use, but might be practical for high production craft use. It's a Kickstarter campaign called Wondercutter, but as a Kickstarter item, there's a risk involved.

As I own a laser cutter which cuts cardboard quite cleanly, it's on the top of my suggestion list.

Answer (score 2):

Xacto knife is the artist standard for cutting mats when mounting pictures. Mats are made from a very thick cardstock. You already have the stencil, you may want to get a  French Curve ruler. That helps with stability while cutting.

LINKS
See the xacto website for knives & blade options.  There’s a wiki link about french curves. Also an article about mat board and different thicknesses of cardstock as well as foamcore board.

[Https://xacto.com/products/cutting-solutions/knives](http://xacto.com)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_curve [3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_curve)

https://www.cansonstudio.com/choosing-framing-papers-and-mat-boards